# How to use program like Autocad of 32 bit work on computer having OS Windows 7 of 64 bit?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit, autocad

I purchased Dell note book and it came with Windows 7, 64 bit.

Now when I try to install AUTOCAD 2008 version, which is in 32 bit, I am unable  to run the software. I get message that you can't run 32 bit program on a 64 bit processor.

What to do?

Comment: I tried downloading the Windows solution of downloading Windows XP mode. My computer shut down three times in the process of trying to download the Windows XP mode. Has anyone been successful at downloading the XP mode and having it run 32 bit AutoCAD?

Comment: Do you get AutoCAD through your school or employer?  Try getting AutoCAD 2011 64-bit - you can open and save in the older 2008 format.

Answer (score 12):

According to this http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/ps/item?siteID=123112&id=9450261&linkID=9240617 you cannot install AutoCAD 32 bit on 64 bit operating systems. You will need a 64 bit version of AutoCAD.

Note that this is a limitation of AutoCAD and many 32 bit applications work fine in 64 bit windows.

Answer (score 3):

That is odd because most programs are 32 bit!  If you have Win 7 Pro or an XP License, you can install this in a 32 bit Virtual Machine which is nicely integrated in Windows 7.
http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This has been an issue with AutoCAD for several years. Although Autodesk makes sure that both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of their software is available, some third-party add-ons will only work with the 32-bit versions.

If you have a 64-bit OS and have some of these expensive addons, then you really want to install AutoCAD as a 32-bit program. See [here](http://discussion.autodesk.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=6384299&#6384299) for a method that should allow you to install AutoCAD 2008 as 32-bit on your 64-bit computer if that's what you really need to do.